# jquery .addclass and remove class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

on my code i have a button and if the user clicks the button i try to change a timer which displays on ui by 20 minutes

this was my ui code

[image]

this was the function where the user clicks the button then it will get called and following lines get executed

```js
$('input[name$="timer[1]"').addClass('increaseTimer').removeClass('inputTimer');
```

The class name gets changed while clicking the button, but the timer is not getting increased

the UI shows the time of input timer class

**Increase timer code:**

```js
$(".increaseTimer").datetimepicker({

  ignoreReadonly:true,

  format: 'LT',

  defaultDate: genDate()+' 00:20'

});
```

**Input timer code:**

```js
$(".inputTimer").datetimepicker({

  ignoreReadonly:true,

  format: 'LT',

  defaultDate: genDate()+' 00:00'

});
```

the increase timer is working only if the input timer is not used in UI itself, at that time the increase timer is applying while clicking the button

the remove class is applied , but the UI shows the timer and it not get removed from UI

What wrong in my code

please helpme out

Comment: Changing the class dynamically won't move the datetime pickers correspondingly.

Comment: @Barmar how to approach these kind of scenario

Comment: When you add the class, you need to update the widget options. `.addClass(".inputTimer").datetimepicker("option", "defaultDate", genDate() + ' 00:00')`

Comment: The cause: `$(selector)` only finds elements that exist at the time that code runs.  They're not "dynamic queries"

Comment: This seems like it might be an XY problem - you're only changing the "default date" so if they user picks a date, then this change won't have any effect (or that's how it appears)

Comment: @Barmar .addClass(".inputTimer").datetimepicker("option", "defaultDate", genDate() + ' 00:20') still doesn't change the ui

Comment: @Barmar while adding the class when i update the widget options still it doesnt get updated? what might be the reason

Comment: Because you configured the widget to the elements that were selected when the page was loaded. Changing the class doesn't change that.